# NextJS 13 with app router how to add Microsoft Clarity script to head?

Tags: next.js, ms-clarity

I'm trying to add Microsoft Clarity to my website. I've tried to add it using next/head and next/script but It won't let me the use script in the head.
When I implement it like below script is not added to head and clarity can not properly show me what the users really see.

Edit: I tried to use         strategy="afterInteractive"
that did not work, too. Script not in head.

Edit2: I added pages/_document.js as stated in docs. Script not loading. [Docs NextJS](https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/no-before-interactive-script-outside-document)

I'm moving my website from Nuxt3 to NextJS. In Nuxt3 I managed to add a script to head section of the app but I couldn't find a way to do same in NextJS 13 using app router. Here is the code for reference.

```js
export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode
}) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <Script
          id="ms-clarity"
          dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
            __html: `(function (c, l, a, r, i, t, y) {
            c[a] =
                c[a] ||
                function () {
                    (c[a].q = c[a].q || []).push(arguments);
                };
            t = l.createElement(r);
            t.async = 1;
            t.src = "https://www.clarity.ms/tag/" + i;
            y = l.getElementsByTagName(r)[0];
            y.parentNode.insertBefore(t, y);
        })(window, document, "clarity", "script", "keyyyy");
        `,
          }}
        />
      </head>
      <body className={inter.className}>{children}</body>
    </html >
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else curious, I got this to work by putting the Script tag *outside* of the Head tag, and putting the function inside of the Script tag.

This is in my root layout page (src/app/layout.tsx)

```js
const RootLayout = async ({ children }: React.PropsWithChildren) => {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      {/* Clarity Script */}
      <Script strategy="lazyOnload" id="clarity-script">
        {`
          (function(c,l,a,r,i,t,y){
            c[a]=c[a]||function(){(c[a].q=c[a].q||[]).push(arguments)};
            t=l.createElement(r);t.async=1;t.src="https://www.clarity.ms/tag/"+i;
            y=l.getElementsByTagName(r)[0];y.parentNode.insertBefore(t,y);
          })(window, document, "clarity", "script", "keyyyyyy");
        `}
      </Script>

      <body>
        <main>{children}</main>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
};

export default RootLayout;
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option :

```
export  const Clarity =()=>{
  return(
    <script
  dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
    __html: `
        (function(c,l,a,r,i,t,y){
            c[a] = c[a] || function () { (c[a].q = c[a].q || []).push(arguments) };
            t=l.createElement(r);
            t.async=1;
            t.src="https://www.clarity.ms/tag/"+i;
            y=l.getElementsByTagName(r)[0];
            y.parentNode.insertBefore(t,y);
        })(window, document, "clarity", "script", "XXXXXXXXX");`,
  }}
/>
)
}
```